# Duda sobre el script de Google ads en un website

Tags: javascript, google-ads

Estoy tratando de ayudar a mi hermano con su campaña de Google Ads, ya que yo le construí el website (sin usar Wordpress), y él me pasó el codigo que debo insertar en el head de la página a seguir. El problema es que en el código hay una función con el parámetro <event_parameters> y  entiendo que es un placeholder para los parámetros que van en dicha función. Busqué en internet qué debo poner ahí y no he encontrado nada, ni en inglés ni en español. Este es el código completo que me dicen que inserte:

```
function gtagSendEvent(url) { var callback = function () { if (typeof url === 'string') { window.location = url; } }; gtag('event', 'conversion_event_contact', { 'event_callback': callback, 'event_timeout': 2000, <event_parameters> }); return false; } </script>
```

Agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Comment: No he conseguido encontrar nada sobre el evento "conversion_event_contact". Supongo que es un evento personalizado, por tanto, los parámetros a mandar también deben ser personalizados.

https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/gtagjs/reference/events
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72224530/17127043
https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/gtagjs/configure?hl=es-419